# Using OrderedDict to output list in reverse order from CSV file

Tags: python, collections

I need to have a import a CSV file containing:

```
name,mean performance,std dev
Alice,100,0
Bob,100,5 
Clare,100,10
Dennis,90,0
Eva,90,5
```

and have the output come out sorted as:

```
{'Dennis': (90.0, 0.0), 'Clare': (100.0, 10.0), 'Eva': (90, 5.0), 'Bob': (100.0, 5.0), 'Alice': (100.0, 0.0)}
```

So far I have:

```
import csv
import collections

def sailorPerf(filename, header=True):

    with open(filename, mode='r') as csvfile:
        r = csv.reader(csvfile)
        if header==True:
            next(r)
        od = collections.OrderedDict((row[0], row[1]) for row in r)
    print (od)
```

Which outputs:

```
OrderedDict([('Alice', ' 100'), ('Bob', ' 100'), ('Clare', ' 100'), ('Dennis', ' 90'), ('Eva', ' 90')])
```

I was wondering how to add the third column into the result as well as change the formatting to have the ordereddict part removed from the output and change around how the output is given to have the name and output as it is in the intended result.

Comment: How is your order reversed? I don't get how `'Dennis'` comes first

Comment: It's based on the scoring system for sailing competitions so the lower the score the higher you rank, so Dennis having the lowest score and lowest standard deviation means that he is first.

Comment: I added an answer, you need to sort based on the two columns

Answer (score 0):

change `(row[0], row[1])` to `(row[0], tuple(row[1:]))` to have the second as a list containing all elements from index 1 - end of list then cast it as a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the data, by the second and third columns casting to int:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def sailorPerf(filename, header=True):
    with open(filename, mode='r') as csvfile:
        r = csv.reader(csvfile)
        if header:
            next(r)
        od = OrderedDict((name, tuple(rest)) 
                  for name,*rest in sorted(r, key=lambda x: (int(x[1]), int(x[2]))))
        return od


print(sailorPerf("test.txt"))
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Dennis', ('90', '0')), ('Eva', ('90', '5')),
        ('Alice', ('100', '0')), ('Bob', ('100', '5')),
        ('Clare', ('100', '10'))])
```

If you really don't want to see the OrderedDict you can could call `list(od.items)`:

```
print(list(sailorPerf("test.txt").items()))

OrderedDict([('Dennis', ('90', '0')), ('Eva', ('90', '5')), 
          ('Alice', ('100', '0')), ('Bob', ('100', '5')),
                 ('Clare', ('100', '10'))])
```

For python2 just unpack:

```
def sailorPerf(filename, header=True):
    with open(filename, mode='r') as csvfile:
        r = csv.reader(csvfile)
        if header==True:
            next(r)
        od = OrderedDict((nm, (mn, std))) 
                  for nm, mn, std in sorted(r,key=lambda x: (int(x[1]),int(x[2]))))
        return od
```